# ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig.With(...) Method is missing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, servicestack

I have an Asp.Net MVC application that has a few errors with a cause that I can't seem to track down. I think they are related, but I am not familiar enough with ServiceStack to tell for sure.

For starters, I keep on seeing the following exception thrown:

```
Method not found: 'ServiceStack.Text.JsConfigScope ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig.With(
System.Nullable`1<Boolean>, System.Nullable`1<Boolean>, 
System.Nullable`1<Boolean>, System.Nullable`1<Boolean>, 
System.Nullable`1<Boolean>, System.Nullable`1<Boolean>,
System.Nullable`1<Boolean>, System.Nullable`1<Boolean>, 
System.Nullable`1<ServiceStack.Text.DateHandler>,
System.Nullable`1<ServiceStack.Text.TimeSpanHandler>,
System.Nullable`1<ServiceStack.Text.PropertyConvention>,
System.Nullable`1<Boolean>, System.Nullable`1<Boolean>,
System.String, System.Func`2<System.Type,System.String>,
System.Func`2<System.String,System.Type>,
System.Nullable`1<Boolean>, System.Nullable`1<Boolean>,
System.Nullable`1<Boolean>, System.Nullable`1<Boolean>,
System.Nullable`1<Boolean>, System.Nullable`1<Boolean>,
System.Nullable`1<Int32>, ServiceStack.EmptyCtorFactoryDelegate,
System.String[])'.
```

This method isn't actually being called in my own code though. This error seems to keep on occurring within ServiceStack. One example is when trying to get a typed session:

AppServiceBase.cs

```
using ServiceStack;

namespace MyWebProject.ServiceInterface
{
    public abstract class AppServiceBase : Service
    {
        public virtual UserSession UserSession
        {
            get { 
                return SessionAs<UserSession>(); // Throws an error when called
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That'll then give me a stack trace like this:

```
[MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'ServiceStack.Text.JsConfigScope ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig.With(System.Nullable`1<Boolean>, System.Nullable`1<Boolean>, System.Nullable`1<Boolean>, System.Nullable`1<Boolean>, System.Nullable`1<Boolean>, System.Nullable`1<Boolean>, System.Nullable`1<Boolean>, System.Nullable`1<Boolean>, System.Nullable`1<ServiceStack.Text.DateHandler>, System.Nullable`1<ServiceStack.Text.TimeSpanHandler>, System.Nullable`1<ServiceStack.Text.PropertyConvention>, System.Nullable`1<Boolean>, System.Nullable`1<Boolean>, System.String, System.Func`2<System.Type,System.String>, System.Func`2<System.String,System.Type>, System.Nullable`1<Boolean>, System.Nullable`1<Boolean>, System.Nullable`1<Boolean>, System.Nullable`1<Boolean>, System.Nullable`1<Boolean>, System.Nullable`1<Boolean>, System.Nullable`1<Int32>, ServiceStack.EmptyCtorFactoryDelegate, System.String[])'.]
   ServiceStack.Redis.RedisClient.Exec(Func`2 action) +0
   ServiceStack.Redis.RedisClient.Get(String key) +241
   ServiceStack.Redis.RedisClientManagerCacheClient.Get(String key) +142
   ServiceStack.SessionExtensions.SessionAs(ICacheClient cache, IRequest httpReq, IResponse httpRes) +150
   ...Where it was called from and the rest of the stack.
```

This seems to happen with anything that calls `JsConfig.With()` somewhere. Any insight as to what might be causing this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a potential version mismatch. Ensure the version of `ServiceStack.Text.dll` is the same as `ServiceStack.Redis.dll`.

Comment: @mythz That was it. If you want to make your comment an answer so I can choose it, that'd be cool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever method signatures don't match between assemblies or there's a runtime `MissingMethodException` it's likely that there's a version mismatch between the dependencies, which updating your NuGet packages should resolve.

ServiceStack libraries are deployed in lock-step together with the same version number so you can tell if the dlls are the same version by comparing Assembly Version info.